# Ordenar por fecha consultas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo esta consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS registros, DATE(fechaValidacion) AS fecha, nodo_id, motivorechazo_id FROM registro JOIN prueba GROUP BY fecha,nodo_id,motivorechazo_id;
```

Lo cual arroja el siguiente resultado

```
#   Fecha       nodo motivo_id 
1   2019-07-26  403 
789 2019-07-24  403 1
2   2019-07-30  403 2
7   2019-07-24  403 4
2   2019-07-24  403 5
1   2019-07-25  403 6
104 2019-07-24  403 8
14  2019-07-24  403 9
10  2019-07-24  403 10
4   2019-07-26  403 11
```

El # es el numero de registro q encontro en ese día por el numero del motivo, es decir, encontro 789 registros por motivo id. Pero lo que quisiera es que la fecha apareciera en orden descendente, es decir que aparesca primero el dia 24 con el numero de registros y despues el dia siguiente, algo como este estilo

```
#   Fecha       nodo motivo_id 
1   2019-07-24  403 
789 2019-07-24  403 1
37  2019-07-25  403 1
90  2019-07-26  403 1
2   2019-07-27  403 1
```

Comment: ODERDE BY DATE(fechaValidacion) DESC

Comment: Efectivamente el Order by me sirvio, ahora mismo lo agrego como respuesta

Comment: De nada saludos :D

Comment: En el texto dices que quieres ordenar por fecha de manera descendente, sin embargo en los datos de ejemplo de salida ordenas las fechas en orden ascendente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar un order by, ya se por fecha,nodo_id,motivorechazo_id o el campo que requieras, quedaría así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS registros, 
DATE(fechaValidacion) AS fecha, nodo_id, 
motivorechazo_id 
FROM registro 
JOIN prueba 
GROUP BY fecha,nodo_id,motivorechazo_id
ORDER BY fecha
```

`ORDER BY` te permite ordenar de forma ascendente o descendente, para ello colocas después del campo el como quieres que se ordene.

Ejemplo:

```
ORDER BY fecha ASC  - para ascendente
ORDER BY fecha DESC  - para descendente
```